# How can I create a wrapper component for entire app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add some analytics tracking for my react app. Basically just using a component to add global event listeners and then handle the event appropriately in that component.

I want to wrap my entire app in this component and for it to pick up `componentWillUpdate` prop changes so I can react to page changes using `prop.location`. My problem is I don't know how to setup my wrapper component to do this. I know the concept of HOC can help wrap one component and I've tested that to work but I want this to be a more generic and global component.

Tracker.js

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import * as React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

import TrackingManager from './TrackingManager'
import ScriptManager from "./ScriptManager"
import { isLeftClickEvent } from "../utils/Utils"

const trackingManager = new TrackingManager()

const config = {
    useTagManager: true,
    tagManagerAccount: 'testCccount', 
    tagManagerProfile: 'testProfile', 
    tagManagerEnvironment: 'dev'
}

/**
 * compares the locations of 2 components, mostly taken from:
 * http://github.com/nfl/react-metrics/blob/master/src/react/locationEquals.js
 *
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function locationEquals(a, b) {
  if (!a && !b) {
    return true;
  }
  if ((a && !b) || (!a && b)) {
    return false;
  }

  return (
    a.pathname === b.pathname && a.search === b.search && a.state === b.state
  );
}

/**
 * Tracking container which wraps the supplied Application component.
 * @param Application
 * @param beforeAction
 * @param overrides
 * @returns {object}
 */
const track = Application =>
  class TrackingContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this._addClickListener()
      this._addSubmitListener()
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      // prevent side effects by removing listeners upon unmount
      this._removeClickListener()
      this._removeSubmitListener()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // if and only if the location has changed we need to track a
      // new pageview
      if (!locationEquals(this.props.location, prevProps.location)) {
        this._handlePageView(this.props)
      }
    }


    _addClickListener = () => {
      // bind to body to catch clicks in portaled elements (modals, tooltips, dropdowns)
      document.body.addEventListener("click", this._handleClick)
    }

    _removeClickListener = () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", this._handleClick)
    }

    _addSubmitListener = () => {
      document.body.addEventListener("submit", this._handleSubmit)
    }

    _removeSubmitListener = () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("submit", this._handleSubmit)
    }

    _handleSubmit = event => {
        console.log(event.target.name)
    }

    _handleClick = event => {
      // ensure the mouse click is an event we're interested in processing,
      // we have discussed limiting to external links which go outside the
      // react application and forcing implementers to use redux actions for
      // interal links, however the app is not implemented like that in
      // places, eg: Used Search List. so we're not enforcing that restriction
      if (!isLeftClickEvent(event)) {
        return
      }

      // Track only events when triggered from a element that has 
      // the `analytics` data attribute.
      if (event.target.dataset.analytics !== undefined) {
        trackingManager.event('pageName', 'User')
      }
    }

    _handlePageView = route => {
      console.log('CHANGE PAGE EVENT')
      console.log(route)
    }

    /**
     * Return  tracking script. 
     */
    _renderTrackingScript() {

        /**
         * If utag is already loaded on the page we don't  want to load it again
         */
        if (window.utag !== undefined) return

        if (config.useTagManager === false) return

        /**
         * Load  utag script. 
         */
        return (
          <ScriptManager
            account={config.tagManagerAccount}
            profile={config.tagManagerProfile}
            environment={config.tagManagerEnvironment}
          />
        )
    }


    render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Application {...this.props} {...this.state} />
          {this.props.children}
          {this._renderTrackingScript()}
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }

export default track
```

With my index.js I want to do something similar to this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './lib/store'
import history from './lib/history'
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'
import PageLoader from './components/PageLoader/PageLoader'
import { 
    DEFAULT_PATH, 
    LOGIN_PATH, 
    LOGOUT_PATH, 
    USER_PATH,
} from './lib/paths'

const Login = Loadable({ loader: () => import('./scenes/Auth/Login' /* webpackChunkName: 'login' */), loading: PageLoader })
const Logout = Loadable({ loader: () => import('./scenes/Auth/Logout'/* webpackChunkName: 'logout' */), loading: PageLoader })
const User = Loadable({ loader: () => import('./scenes/Auth/User'/* webpackChunkName: 'user' */), loading: PageLoader })


import Track from './lib/tracking/Tracker'

import './assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss'
import './bootstrap-ds.css'
import './index.css'
import './assets/stylesheets/scenes.scss'

ReactDOM.render((
// This is an example of what I want to accomplish
<Track>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={LOGIN_PATH} component={Login}  />
                <Route path={LOGOUT_PATH} component={Logout} />
                <Route path={USER_PATH} component={User} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
</Track>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

So, basically where the `<Track>` component can wrap the entire app and still use the props and check if they update. Is there a way to do this? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) seems to be your use case here. You want a decoupled way to share data between components in the same tree. Your wrapper could implement a `Provider`, and all components that are interest on the shared value will implement a `Consumer`. `HOC` and `render Props` are useful to share stateful logic, not state itself.

```
const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext()

const Wrapper = ({children}) =>{
    return(
        <Provider value={mySharedValue}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}

const NestedChildren = () =>{
    return(
        <Consumer>
            {context => <div>{context}</div>}
        </Consumer>
    )
}

const App = () =>{
    return(
        <Wrapper>
            <Child> <NestedChild /> </Child>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

Comment: But with this approach I won't be able to track prop changes at the top level will I? For instance I mentioned I want to check for location change using props and trigger some event in the Wrapper component..in this case the can't track those in the wrapper

Comment: Put the logic inside wrapper, and change the context's value accordingly. Again, HOC won't hel you here, you want to pass state as props. Have you consider to use redux?

Comment: Yes, trying to work with a non redux dependent solution right now. There a lot of state data we dont' actually store in redux.

Comment: So context it's the way to go.

Comment: Redux itself use context under the hood

Comment: Perfect. Haven't worked with context api yet but had one more question...are there watcher functions for when context is updated. Just trying to thing..how would I trigger and event in the Wrapper function if i navigate to a new page in my app for instance

Comment: Tha's the advantage of new context API `React.createContext`, now context is like any other prop, modify it and React will react to it haha

Comment: ohhh..that's sick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We accomplished something like this with [`react-capture-metrics`](https://github.com/stackshirts/react-capture-metrics).

You provide your analytics API to a top level provider like so:

```
import { MetricsProvider } from 'react-capture-metrics'

const analytics = {
  track: (name, properties) => window.analytics.track(name, properties),
  page: (name, properties, category) => window.analytics.page(...(category ? [category, name, properties] : [name, properties]))
}

function App () {
  return (
    <MetricsProvider analytics={analytics} properties={{ appVersion: pkg.version }}>
      // ...the rest of your app
    </MetricsProvider>
  )
}
```

Then render a `PageView` component wherever you want to call `analytics.page()`.

```
function Page() {
  const { PageView } = useMetrics({
    variantId, 
    // ...properties to capture
  }, { ready: variantId !== undefined })
  return (
    <PageView 
      name="Home"
      category="Customer"
      ready={/* some useState value perhaps */ }
    >
      // ...
    </PageView>
  )  
}
```

You can use `ready` to delay calling the event until all the properties you want to pass are loaded. Or you can use `pageKey` to call the event when the user navigates to the same page but with different params.