# How to add a watcher for context change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on adding an analytics tracker to my react app. I want to primarily capture 2 things:
1) All click events.
2) All page change events.

I was trying to figure out how to approach this problem and found some help on SO with this:
[How can I create a wrapper component for entire app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204995/how-can-i-create-a-wrapper-component-for-entire-app/57205047)

The above post basically had me creating a parent wrapper and using the React Context API to pass data to the nested elements. The idea is great, but I'm still missing a few pieces here after reading the context API.

Heres what I have following that pattern.

Tracker.js

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import * as React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

import TrackingManager from './TrackingManager'
import ScriptManager from "./ScriptManager"
import { isLeftClickEvent } from "../utils/Utils"

const trackingManager = new TrackingManager()
export const TrackerProvider = React.createContext()

/**
 * Tracking container which wraps the supplied Application component.
 * @param Application
 * @param beforeAction
 * @param overrides
 * @returns {object}
 */
class Tracker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        pageName: ''
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this._addClickListener()
      this._addSubmitListener()
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      // prevent side effects by removing listeners upon unmount
      this._removeClickListener()
      this._removeSubmitListener()
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      console.log('TRACKER UPDATE')
    }

    pageLoad = pageName => {
        console.log('LOADING PAGE')
        this.setState({ pagename }, trackingManager.page(this.state))
    }
    /**
     * Add global event listener for click events.
     */
    _addClickListener = () => document.body.addEventListener("click", this._handleClick)
    /**
     * Remove global event listern for click events. 
     */
    _removeClickListener = () => document.body.removeEventListener("click", this._handleClick)
    /**
     * Add global event listener for submit events. 
     */
    _addSubmitListener = () => document.body.addEventListener("submit", this._handleSubmit)
    /**
     * Remove global event listern for click events. 
     */
    _removeSubmitListener = () => document.body.removeEventListener("submit", this._handleSubmit)

    _handleSubmit = event => {
        console.log(event.target.name)
    }

    _handleClick = event => {
      // ensure the mouse click is an event we're interested in processing,
      // we have discussed limiting to external links which go outside the
      // react application and forcing implementers to use redux actions for
      // interal links, however the app is not implemented like that in
      // places, eg: Used Search List. so we're not enforcing that restriction
      if (!isLeftClickEvent(event)) {
        return
      }

      // Track only events when triggered from a element that has 
      // the `analytics` data attribute.
      if (event.target.dataset.analytics !== undefined) {
        let analyticsTag = event.target.dataset.analytics
        console.log("Analytics:", analyticsTag)
        trackingManager.event("eventAction", {"eventName": analyticsTag, "pageName": "Something"})
      }
    }

    /**
     * Return  tracking script. 
     */
    _renderTrackingScript() {

        /**
         * If utag is already loaded on the page we don't  want to load it again
         */
        if (window.utag !== undefined) return

        /**
         * Load utag script. 
         */
        return (
          <ScriptManager
            account={process.env.ANALYTICS_TAG_ACCOUNT}
            profile={process.env.ANALYTICS_TAG_PROFILE}
            environment={process.env.ANALYTICS_TAG_ENV}
          />
        )
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <TrackerProvider.Provider value={
          {
            state: this.state, 
            loadPage: this.pageLoad
          }
        }>
          {this.props.children}
          {this._renderTrackingScript()}
        </TrackerProvider.Provider>
      )
    }
  }

export default Tracker
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './lib/store'
import history from './lib/history'



import MyComp from './containers/components/MyComp'
import Tracker from './lib/tracking/Tracker'

import './assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss'
import './bootstrap-ds.css'
import './index.css'
import './assets/stylesheets/scenes.scss'

ReactDOM.render((
<Tracker>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={'/analytics'} component={MyComp}  />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
</Tracker>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

MyComp.js

```
import React from 'react
import { TrackerProvider } from '../../lib/tracking/Tracker

const MyComp = () => {
    return (
        <TrackerProvider.Consumer>
         {context =>
              <>
                <div>This is my test page for track events for analytics</div>
                <button data-analytics="TEST_BUTTON">Test Analytics</button>
              </>
         }
        </TrackerProvider.Consumer>
    )
}

export default MyComp
```

Here's what I'm struggling with a little bit:
1. When I load a nested child component that consumes the context, how do I notify the Parent (`<Tracker />`) to trigger some function? Similar to `componentDidUpdate`.

In essence a user navigates to the `MyComp` page and the `pageLoad` function is fired in the `Tracker`.
2. How do I update the Context from `MyComp` without depending on some click event in the render method to run a funciton. So maybe in `componentDidUpdate` I can update the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you had `connect` from `react-redux`. Redux already provides its state to all the components in your app, so if you're already using Redux, you don't need to mess with the context API directly.

It's possible to create a higher-order component (a component that takes a component and returns a component) and attach event listeners to that capable of catching all the click events in your app.

A click disptaching HOC might look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import logClick from '../path/to/log/clicks.js';

const ClickLogger = Component => (...props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return <div onClick={e => dispatch(logClick(e))}>
    <Component {...props } />
  </div>;
};
```

`logClick` will be a Redux action creator. Once you've got your log actions dispatching to Redux, you can use redux middleware to handle your log actions. If you want to hit a tracking pixel on a server or something, you could use [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) to trigger the logging effects.

If you want to track every page load, you can create a higher-order component which uses the [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) with an empty array (`[]`) as the second argument. This will fire an effect on the first render, but no subsequent renders.

Comment: We do use redux but there are still several component where we store state locally and not in redux. So there might be data that exists we need but isn't in redux.

Comment: Why not wrap every page in a Redux provider whether it uses it directly or not? I have a higher-order component called `page` which provides Redux and other cross-cutting concerns to every page in my app. The alternative you're suggesting is to essentially roll your own react-redux just for logging.

Comment: Ahh, that does make a lot of sense. Also, not to fanboy over here but love your online content...been debating signing up for the course on your website and this convo is pushing me in the right direction ;)

Comment: If I was using an HOC, is it possbile to still just add a global event listener and just listten to every click and just filter out the ones with select data attributes? I want to wrap this around the entire app and not do this component by component.

Comment: That's what the HOC does, yes. You can apply it at any level in your app. If you want all pages to log, you technically could wrap it around your app's root component, assuming that your Redux store is already provided at that level.